# Android Fragment Re-size

Tags: android, list, fragment

I am developing an application Android to have the option to reduce the size of a fragment is possible?

Example:
    Min width = 200
     Max width= 500

View:
    Fragment 1 - CLIENT LIST        |<->|          Fragment - CLIENT DETAILS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since a fragment (usually) creates a view , you can simply change the view's size.
however,  it might be a little slow , depending on the complexity of the views around , and the API you are targeting (since new APIs use the gpu too for the layout phase) .

Comment: Thanks, I already imagined that he could not do it hehe.

Supposed to be something like Primefaces: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutElement.jsf

Where the user can resize the column.

Comment: i didn't say it's impossible . it's very possible . it just might be a little slow , depending on what you have:device,API,views,...

Comment: A yes, sorry I understood wrong. The devices were all Galaxy Tab 10. Thank you for your attention: D

Comment: anyway, in order to achieve the results you wish , you can use the layoutParams of the view that was created by the fragment ,change them (and probably others as well) , and set the again to be the new ones.